# How to make a dynamic frontline system for my game?

Tags: mathematics, gui, unreal-4, maps, fluid-dynamics

**My problem:**

Basically the units, units meaning soldiers or vehicles, influence the frontline by moving into the opponents territory (See example image).

I'm trying to understand where to even start with this. I honestly have no idea what kind algorithm would be used to create this kind of system.

**Example Image:**

[image: Dynamic map example]

More info about the example:
https://www.eugensystems.com/steel-division-normandy-44-gameplay-dynamic-front-line/

This system is not node or tile based, but is fully dynamic (almost looks like a fluid simulation lol). I figured out I would render the line by using spline interpolation with points, but I don't understand the math behind the system itself (the part that controls how the line moves and creates points).

It's really cool and I would love to know where I would even start. Any free references would be highly appreciated.

**Thank you!**

Comment: Look into Voronoi Diagrams and Influence Maps (applied in video game AI). There is material on those topics online, including on other questions on this site. I think you should try, and ask if you run into trouble.

Comment: Thank you I'll look up those subjects.